# Find my feedback in the Feedback-Hub

Tags: feedback, feedback-hub

I've submitted several items of feedback through the Feedback Hub on PC & mobile. Is there a way I can see all the suggestions I've made and those I've voted for?

I'd like to see if there are any answers, votes or status updates for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard filtering options to see feedback you've submitted. To do so, in the Feedback app:

1. From the hamburger menu, select "Feedback"
2. Tap on the filtering options after "Refine:"
3. Under "Filter", select "My feedback" (set other options per preference)

[image]